# Run it twice side pot case

Tags: rules

I have read the earlier answers about run it twice and its meaning what I don't get is what will happen in case of side pots and all the players are all-in in different rounds.
Suppose there are 4 players having amounts as 30,40,60,100 and all of them decided to run it twice. How will run it twice run in that case is it like this -
Firstly the first side pot winner is decided and game is run twice by dividing the pot. Then the next pot is again run twice for all the players in that pot and again run it twice is done and so on.
Or
For only last side pot all players who are contributing in the pot are considered for running it twice and not the other players.

Answer (score 1):

Because multi way all-ins are already so complicated it will usually be run once, even online. But if you'd run it `x` times, then you would divide each pot into `x` equal parts and treat each of those normally.

So in your example stacks are 30,40,60,100.

So main pot is 120. Side pot 1 is 30. Side pot 2 is 40.

Say you want to run it five times then each time main pot is 24, side pot 1 is 6 and side pot 2 is 8. So each time 24 + 6 + 8 = 38 chips are awarded to players 5 times in total.

Comment: So basically if I want to make run it twice Functionality in an online game then I should implement only for the case when only two final players remain for the final side pot and for other pots and player who are all-in the game should run normally

Comment: I dont really understand I am sorry.

Comment: Suppose there is a case in which stacks are 30,40,200,200 and player with 40 chips goes all-in and other player calls then main pot will be 120, side pot 1 will be 30 and then flop cards will come with stacks being 0,0,160,160 and now suppose 1 player with 160 chips goes all-in and other player calls then side pot 2 will be 320 with turn and river to come, assuming run it twice is enabled for all now in an online game should I run the cards twice for only side pot 2 or for all players

Comment: I understand now. But it is really complex. You for sure can't make it so that you run twice for only some players and not for others. It would make things way too complex for the players. The way I see it you have two options. Of course if one player does not want to run it twice then don't run it twice. Two options. 1) only run it twice in a headsup pot and in a multiway pot always run it once. For many it is way to hard to see what is going on in multiway pots running it more than once. 2) if all players want to run it twice for all players. I'd for sure go for option 1.

Comment: While it does make sense, I don't think this ever happens in practice, I don't remember ever seeing something like this. It's either multi-way-pot or run-it-more-than-once, never both. Interesting situation though...

Answer (score 0):

> I have read the earlier answers about run it twice and its meaning what I don't get is what will happen in case of side pots and all the players are all-in in different rounds.

I believe it cannot be ran twice or more, while there are still players competing for the pot that are not all in. That is to say at this point in the action the second board cannot be dealt at this point.

I suppose it is possible to agree to run it again after showdown for an all in player but I have never seen this happen, I would ask for a decision and think it is anybody's guess how that would go. I have as much high limit experience as anybody in the business, and have never seen a scenario like this. Doing this might be a fun and innovative feature in your program, or it might not be something worthwhile since it is rarely if ever done in the real world of poker.

> Suppose there are 4 players having amounts as 30,40,60,100 and all of
>   them decided to run it twice. How will run it twice run in that case
>   is it like this - Firstly the first side pot winner is decided and
>   game is run twice by dividing the pot. Then the next pot is again run
>   twice for all the players in that pot and again run it twice is done
>   and so on. Or For only last side pot all players who are contributing
>   in the pot are considered for running it twice and not the other
>   players.

You do not run it twice for each side pot. You simply run it twice, once and that determines all the winners and losers accordingly, and you decide the side pots as usual Deciding the first side pot first and working back to the main pot.

Comment: You do not run it twice for each side pot. You simply run it twice, once and that determines all the winners and losers accordingly, and you decide the side pots as usual Deciding the first side pot first and working back to the main pot - so if I am understanding it correctly the cards which are dealt twice on board will come after last two players goes all-in and then for new board and old board we should evaluate all pots side pots and main pot

Comment: Yeah I think you have it. You know what ever you write to figure out winners and losers in your program should also be able to figure the side pots with a little extension.